# Can medical information (such as expected time until a terminal condition occurs) be witheld from minors?

Tags: united-states, medical, minor

(not including mental issues) Do medical professionals have an obligation to tell the patient their findings, or can they just tell the parents and leave it up to their judgement whether or not the minor will be informed?

Comment: "time left to live" is nothing any doc will do. "Expected time till a terminal condition happens" is what they might do in some cases, based on experience with some conditions (e.g. cancer)

Comment: Alright I'll rephrase

Comment: This is a very good question. I have faced the issue- I’m a pediatrician. Ethically it is very fraught. Likewise practically. And it’s not a good idea usually (talking teens, not little kids). *Legally* it depends on the state.

Comment: Why isn't it a good idea to tell teens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do medical professionals have an obligation to tell the patient their
> findings, or can they just tell the parents and leave it up to their
> judgement whether or not the minor will be informed?

Generally speaking, parents are "natural guardians" of their children to whom medical communications can be made by medical professionals without directly informing the child. But medical ethics also don't necessarily treat all minors the same. A distinction is made between more mature and less mature minors on a sliding scale.

> **Physicians who treat minors have an ethical duty to promote the autonomy of minor patients by involving them in the medical
> decision-making process to a degree commensurate with their
> abilities.**
>
> When minors request confidential services, physicians should encourage
> them to involve their parents. This includes making efforts to obtain
> the minor’s reasons for not involving his or her parents and
> correcting misconceptions that may be motivating their objections.
>
> Where the law does not require otherwise, physicians should permit a
> competent minor to consent to medical care and should not notify
> parents without the patient’s consent. Depending on the seriousness of
> the decision, competence may be evaluated by physicians for most
> minors. When necessary, experts in adolescent medicine or child
> psychological development should be consulted. Use of the courts for
> competence determinations should be made only as a last resort.
>
> When an immature minor requests contraceptive services,
> pregnancy-related care (including pregnancy testing, prenatal and
> postnatal care, and delivery services), or treatment for sexually
> transmitted disease, measures to prevent sexually transmitted disease,
> drug and alcohol abuse, or mental illness, physicians must recognize
> that requiring parental involvement may be counterproductive to the
> health of the patient. Physicians should encourage parental
> involvement in these situations. However, if the minor continues to
> object, his or her wishes ordinarily should be respected. If the
> physician is uncomfortable with providing services without parental
> involvement, and alternative confidential services are available, the
> minor may be referred to those services. In cases when the physician
> believes that, without parental involvement and guidance, the minor
> will face a serious health threat, and there is reason to believe that
> the parents will be helpful and understanding, disclosing the problem
> to the parents is ethically justified. When the physician does breach
> confidentiality to the parents, he or she must discuss the reasons for
> the breach with the minor prior to the disclosure.
>
> For **minors who are mature enough to be unaccompanied by their
> parents for their examination**, confidentiality of information
> disclosed during an exam, interview, or in counseling should be
> maintained. Such information may be disclosed to parents when the
> patient consents to disclosure. Confidentiality may be justifiably
> breached in situations for which confidentiality for adults may be
> breached, according to Opinion 5.05, “Confidentiality.” In addition,
> confidentiality for immature minors may be ethically breached when
> necessary to enable the parent to make an informed decision about
> treatment for the minor or when such a breach is necessary to avert
> serious harm to the minor.

Source quoted: [AMA Code of Medical Ethics’ Opinion on Adolescent Care](https://journalofethics.ama-assn.org/article/ama-code-medical-ethics-opinion-adolescent-care/2014-11), Opinion 5.055 - Confidential Care for Minors, AMA Council on Ethical and Judicial Affairs (November 2014).

Also, it isn't entirely settled that physicians have a duty to make full disclosure to their adult patients regarding matters such as life expectancy when diagnosed with a terminal condition) if they determine that it is not in the best interests of the patient to receive the full and accurate information. The modern trend is to disfavor this practice unless a patient has given advance consent to it. But the American Medical Association ethics opinions cited below are only advisory guidance to state medical profession regulators who are not obligated by law to adopt it. Some states follow the modern trend expressed in these opinions, but others have not chosen to adopt this view.

Even the modern view, however, affords physicians some discretion in the timing of when disclosures are made based upon the best interests of the patient that they perceive.

There are at least two important ethics opinions on point:

> Opinion 8.08 - Informed Consent
>
> The patient’s right of self-decision can be effectively exercised only
> if the patient possesses enough information to enable an informed
> choice. The patient should make his or her own determination about
> treatment. The physician’s obligation is to present the medical facts
> accurately to the patient or to the individual responsible for the
> patient’s care and to make recommendations for management in
> accordance with good medical practice. The physician has an ethical
> obligation to help the patient make choices from among the therapeutic
> alternatives consistent with good medical practice. Informed consent
> is a basic policy in both ethics and law that physicians must honor,
> unless the patient is unconscious or otherwise incapable of consenting
> and harm from failure to treat is imminent. In special circumstances,
> it may be appropriate to postpone disclosure of information (see
> Opinion 8.122, “Withholding Information from Patients”).
>
> Physicians should sensitively and respectfully disclose all relevant
> medical information to patients. The quantity and specificity of this
> information should be tailored to meet the preferences and needs of
> individual patients. Physicians need not communicate all information
> at one time, but should assess the amount of information that patients
> are capable of receiving at a given time and present the remainder
> when appropriate.
>
> Opinion 8.082 - Withholding Information from Patients
>
> **The practice of withholding pertinent medical information from**
> **patients in the belief that disclosure is medically contraindicated is**
> **known as “therapeutic privilege.” It creates a conflict between the**
> **physician’s obligations to promote patients’ welfare and respect for**
> **their autonomy by communicating truthfully.** Therapeutic privilege does
> not refer to withholding medical information in emergency situations,
> or reporting medical errors (see 8.08, “Informed Consent,” and 8.121,
> “Ethical Responsibility to Study and Prevent Error and Harm”).
>
> **Withholding medical information from patients without their knowledge**
> **or consent is ethically unacceptable.** Physicians should encourage
> patients to specify their preferences regarding communication of their
> medical information, preferably before the information becomes
> available. Moreover, physicians should honor patient requests not to
> be informed of certain medical information or to convey the
> information to a designated proxy, provided these requests appear to
> genuinely represent the patient’s own wishes.
>
> **All information need not be communicated to the patient immediately or**
> **all at once; physicians should assess the amount of information a**
> **patient is capable of receiving at a given time, delaying the**
> **remainder to a later, more suitable time, and should tailor disclosure**
> **to meet patients’ needs and expectations in light of their**
> **preferences.**
>
> Physicians may consider delaying disclosure only if early
> communication is clearly contraindicated. Physicians should continue
> to monitor the patient carefully and offer complete disclosure when
> the patient is able to decide whether or not to receive this
> information. This should be done according to a definite plan, so that
> disclosure is not permanently delayed. Consultation with patients’
> families, colleagues, or an ethics committee may help in assessing the
> balance of benefits and harms associated with delayed disclosure. In
> all circumstances, physicians should communicate with patients
> sensitively and respectfully.

Sources quoted: [AMA Code of Medical Ethics’ Opinions on Informing Patients](https://journalofethics.ama-assn.org/article/ama-code-medical-ethics-opinions-informing-patients/2012-07#:%7E:text=The%20practice%20of%20withholding%20pertinent,their%20autonomy%20by%20communicating%20truthfully.), Opinion 8.08 - Informed Consent and Opinion 8.082 - Withholding Information from Patients, AMA Council on Ethical and Judicial Affairs (July 2012).

Comment: Is this primarily an ethical issue as opposed to a legal one? Legally, parents are informed by default, and they can choose to keep the information from the patient?

(subjective+ethical) exceptions being: unless the minor is individually treated/evaluated, and they are "informed" and subjectively "mature" and wish to keep it from their parents?

Comment: @belkarx In this context, unethical conduct can give rise to the suspension or loss of a license to practice medicine from state regulatory officials or even civil legal liability.